# SQL Server Matching Records over a Range of Valid Times

Tags: sql, join, relational-database, grouping

I have a trip table which contains information of individual cars traveling in different parts of a city (start time, end time, start location, end location, etc). I also a table with the weather conditions (temp, precipitation, etc.) of said city measured semi-regularly (every 15 to 30 minutes).

```
Trip Table
| TripID  |        StartTime        |       EndTime           | ....
| 1       | 2012-01-10 03:50:00.163 | 2012-01-15 04:15:40.163 |
| 2       | 2012-01-10 03:59:00.113 | 2012-01-15 04:44:25.025 |
| 3       | 2012-01-10 04:10:00.127 | 2012-01-15 04:35:36.064 |

Weather Table
| WeatherID |    ReadingTime      | .... 
| 1         | 2012-01-10 03:45:00 | 
| 2         | 2012-01-10 04:02:05 | 
| 3         | 2012-01-10 04:30:34 | 
| 4         | 2012-01-10 04:45:23 |
```

These weather readings are discrete so to make it (more) continuous I assume the ids valid over a range with the reading time as the midpoint. For example:

- WeatherID 1 condition is valid over 3:45 to 3:53:525
- WeatherID 2 condition is valid over 3:53:525 to 3:16:195
- etc

I want to add a foreign key to the trip table which associates each trip to the weather what was present for the MAJORITY of the trip. For example TripID 2 takes 42 minutes to complete which occurs over two weather readings (WeatherID 2 and 3). So WeatherID 3 will be assigned to the tripID 2 record because more of the trip happens under weatherID 3 rather than weatherID 2.

I understand this is a bit complicated but is it possible to solve using SQL? Any help is appreciated. Thank.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Have you considered using a VIEW to achieve this realtionship, without using a descrete FK relationship?

Comment: I don't think that you should use a discrete FK relationship. My suggestion is to select the reading times that are closest to StartTime and EndTime and then select the weather data between those times. If you really want you can add a field (or actually a binding table between these two) to use as a FK and do the above in a trigger to fill that field.

Comment: What if more than two weather conditions are required to cover the trip, and no single one covers more than half the trip time?  do you want the weather condition that spans the largest portion of the trip? or no weather condition at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using recent version of SQL Server, To get the weather condition that covers the largest portion of the trip, try:

```
with tripSegs (wxId, starttime, endTime)
As (Select w.WeatherId, 
         coalesce(n.readingTime, w.ReadingTime) startTime,
         coalesce(p.readingTime, w.ReadingTime) endTime
    From Weather w
    left Join weather p on p.ReadingTime =
        (Select Max(ReadingTime)
            From Weather
            Where ReadingTime < w.ReadingTime)
    left Join weather n on n.ReadingTime =
        (Select Min(ReadingTime)
            From Weather
            Where ReadingTime > w.ReadingTime)) 
Select t.tripId, w.wxId, 
    case when w.startTime < t.startTime then t.startTime else w.startTime end startTime,
    case when w.endTime > t.endtime then t.endtime else w.endtime end endtime,
    case when w.startTime < t.startTime then t.startTime else w.startTime end -
    case when w.endTime > t.endtime then t.endtime else w.endtime end elapsedEffectiveTime
From Trips t Join tripSegs w 
     On w.starttime < t.endtime 
 And w.endtime > t.startTime
Where case when w.startTime < t.startTime then t.startTime else w.startTime end -
      case when w.endTime > t.endtime then t.endtime else w.endtime end >  
   (Select Max(case when w.startTime < t.startTime then t.startTime else w.startTime end -
               case when w.endTime > t.endtime then t..endtime else w.endtime end) 
    from Trips t
    Join tripSegs w On w.starttime < t.endtime 
        And w.endtime > t.startTime)
```